# Disappearing socks in "Goodnight Moon"

Tags: childrens-novel

What is the significance to the disappearing socks in the "And goodnight mittens" page of "Goodnight Moon"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to author Andrea Menotti ([link](http://andrea-menotti-2drx.squarespace.com/readwithbaby/2009/11/things-you-might-not-have-known-about.html)): She states that the socks disappear because it's too awkward to say goodnight to socks and mittens, so the mittens go first and then the socks reappear to get their turn.
Of course, I don't know where she got this insight from but this is the only explanation I can find other than it just being an oversight of the artist.
Ms Menotti seems to have done a 4 month study of the book and she seems to know a lot about it. Unfortunately, she doesn't cite any references...

Comment: Four months to analyze 84 words of text? I find that questionable at best! ;)

Comment: Hey, she was pacing herself! :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - may be she is reading it over and over again 100s of times while doing house chores? *zing*